# Why ngModel is not changing value of a string in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-forms, ngmodel

the following is the template for a component:

```html
<form>
    <label>Id: </label>
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="t" (keyup.enter)="Up()">
    <label for="pass">Password: </label>
    <input type="password" id="pass">
</form>
```

this is the ts file for the same component:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-login',
    templateUrl: './login.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss']
})
export class LoginComponent {
    t:string='';

    Up(){
        console.log(this.t);
    }
}
```

this is the app.module.ts file:

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        LoginComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        FormsModule
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Whenever I run it and enter something in the textfield and press enter. it prints an empty string. I have added `FormsModule` in the app module. Why is the `t` variable not changing value?

I tried making it `t!:string` but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made [a StackBlitz you can view here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cxsrbn-omqr2k?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts).  When you run that it gives an error message:

```
ERROR
Error: NG01352: If ngModel is used within a form tag, either the name attribute must be set or the form
control must be defined as 'standalone' in ngModelOptions.

Example 1: <input [(ngModel)]="person.firstName" name="first">
Example 2: <input [(ngModel)]="person.firstName" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
```

So that means you need to do one of the two things it suggests there.  I chose to remove the `<form>` tag and now when I type something and press enter it logs it to the console as expected.  Here's [a final StackBlitz with it working](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cxsrbn-dc15tb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)